# Migrating Atmosphere 1.0.0 to 2.X.X breaks Async communication for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, migration, richfaces, atmosphere

Recently I migrated my application from using Atmosphere 1.0.0 to 2.2.4 (along with RichFaces 4.5.3.Final).

The problem that is now showing occurs only using Internet Explorer 8.

When I enter the page such log is produced:

```
27-04-2015 13:16:55 AsynchronousProcessor [ERROR] Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported. Make sure async-supported is set to true in web.xml https://localhost:8443/myapp/__richfaces_push
```

and then all AJAX requests doesn't go back to browser. I need to press F5 to get my results.

In FireFox everything works fine.

Of course async-support is set to true in my web.xml.

The only thing that changed is atmosphere library version. If I go back to 1.0.0 the problem disappears.

I cannot find any reference in documentation about changing the way of configuration, or anything similar.

I tried to add useWebSocket setting set to false (as I know IE8 doesn't support it), but it doesn't help either.

I tried other versions of Atmosphere:

- 2.3.0 - same error
- 2.0.1 - exceptions but with the same meaning "not supported asyncStart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing  setting for all **filters** taking part in communication.

Strange that only Internet Explorer requests couldn't be handled.

Comment: Although you solved this one you should know that RichFaces 4.5.x doesn't support IE 8 and 9.

Comment: Oh yeah. Now i can see that our production running system on RichFaces 4.3 wasn't even supported for customer's IE8. Happily, everything works.